# string index out of range & encoding utf-8 (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, text-files

I always get this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/01/Desktop 3/Projects/univ/number.py", line 11, in <module>
print(line[5])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I just want to read information from a txt file

```
readFile = open("utf.txt", encoding="utf-8").read()
for line in readFile:
print(line[5])
```

I set txt encoding to "utf-8", my IDE also has the same encoding set
One more thing to concider: the file is written in Russian

Answer (score 0):

Your `readFile` variable is a string (because of `.read()` method). When you iterate over it you get one char (this is your `line` variable). Then you try to print sixth element of this one char. Of course you get `IndexError`.